# Multiple Count SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I need to count the number of times each item appears in a column and return the different counts in query. In details, I have a table that saves contact logs and I need to report the number of logs each person entered and group them by x, y, z... x, y and z are all entries of the same column. 
Can someone please help me with this? I am working in MS Access

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the table's data?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to do something like this

```
SELECT Column_With_XYZ, Count(Column_With_XYZ) FROM TABLE_NAME group by Column_With_XYZ;
```

That way you will get the value of the Column_With_XYZ, and the number of times it appears.